# What version of MS Anti-XSS are you using?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, versioning, xss

I see there is [version 1.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) and [3.0 beta](http://www.codeplex.com/AntiXSS), but I can't seem to find a version 2.  Is this just wacky MS versioning?

Are you using 3.0?  Would you recommend it, or should I stick with 1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I would never recommend to use software in a production environment **marked not as stable**. I'm using the version 1.5 and that works quite good for me.

Some weeks ago, I tested it against the patterns from http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html and all of the XSS attacks were identified.

**Update**

Version 4 of the AntiXSS Library is now out for a while (being part of the [Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)) and it's marked as stable and that's what I am using for the moment until there comes a new stable release.

Answer (score 1):

If you [decompile](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+decompiler+freeware) it, you'll see that the core methods are very simple. It may not be marked "stable" but frankly there isn't anything much in there that could be unstable. Go with 3.0 beta, I say.

Comment: You don't have to decompile, it's released under Ms-PL and you can just grab the source code: http://wpl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest